# Phonegap Plugin not working (cordova-plugin-purchase)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

My first Phonegap App. Everything working well except for plugins. I'm trying to install the cordova-plugin-purchase Plugin.

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

I've followed the instructions. And when I run "phonegap plugins" in the console it shows the plugin as being installed.

According to the documentation, there is suppose to be a "store" object that I can reference. I set up the following code to test if it's working:

```
try {

    store.register({
      id: "my.reverse.item.example",
      alias: "example name",
      type: store.CONSUMABLE
    });

} catch(err) {

    alert(err);

}
```

On my real project, I have the real info in when registering the product, but I can't even get that far. In my TryCatch it returns the following alert:

"Can't find variable: store".

So it seems that the plugin isn't even installed correct. I'm not to phonegap plugins, so there's probably something very basic that I'm missing. Do I have to include a link to the plugin JS in my index.html file?

Comment: This is a question for the author of the plugin.

Comment: I think this is more of a question about how to use Phonegap plugins. I've seen other people with issues using this plugin, but I can't even get my system to see that it's installed.

Comment: Even if is is a question of usage, this means the author has NOT made his direction clear and useful. Ask the author, prompt the author for clarity. Best of Luck

Comment: Well thanks for the advice. Honestly, it's probably clear enough I'm just making a mistake somewhere. I know people are using the plugin because I've seen people asking other questions about it. It's my first phonegap app and I'm still trying to figure a lot of stuff out.

Comment: All plugins should have an example equivalent to "hello world". If not, ask the author for such an example.

Comment: Ya, I can't get that working either. So I really have to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Might be that it won't work on the simulator in ios?... I'll have to try a bunch of things.

Comment: Post your code on a public forum, like github or pastebin. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your offer. I was able to get the demo working, but I still can't get it working in my own app. It seems like no plugins will work at all.

And I get get the deviceready event to fire that is detailed here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

If I can't figure it out soon I'll put my code online.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the problem. It seems to be that I didn't include the cordova.js file in my index.html. I don't see why I needed to do that since I've read over and over that you don't need to manually add the cordova files to your html files.

So the plugin works now and I can receive the store data that I setup using the cordova-plugin-purchase plugin tutorials.

Another thing to note once you actually have the plugin installed correctly:
The Bundle Identifier in Xcode needs to match the bundle ID for the In App purchases you are trying to connect to.

Comment: to clarify what you said about `cordova.js`. You *do not need to include a copy of the javascript file* when you build, as the system will add the most appropriate version needed to the bundle. What you *do need to do add the appropriate HTML element* in your HTML file.